# How does heroku charge free plan users after they reach the 1,000 free dyno hours?

Tags: heroku

I have a question regarding Heroku billing. So, every account gets 1,000 free dyno hours per month (if we add credit card info). That is technically enough for 1 app but if there are more than one and they are awake all the time, then I will exceed the 1,000 hours per month. Do you know how I will be charged for extra hours? After 1,000 hours are reached?

2nd question. The other dyno plans (hobby, standard, etc.) charge monthly for like $7, $25, etc. I know these paid accounts never let your app sleep and there is more RAM, free SSL, etc., but the usage pricing still works similar to free plan (with 1,000 free dyno hours and then charged for extra hours). or with these plans I won't be charged more than $7, $25, etc. for dyno hour usages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You won't be charged after 1000 hours is reached. Your Dyno app will just shut down and not run.
2. They don't use free dyno hours. If you are running the app continuously for a month it will be $7, $25 etc. If it is just a day it will charge 1/30 of $7, $25 etc. They are billing hourly use but they won't exceed the monthly advertised price.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Do you happen to know if the non-free plans are for an account, or they are separate for each app in the account. So, basically if I have 3 apps in my account, will I need to pay $25 * 3 for the 3 apps or just $25 for a standard 1x plan?

Comment: They are per app. You can change the plan of each app individually.